# google plus scrolling technique in android

Tags: scroll, google-plus

I was wondering is there a way we can replicate how google plus scrolling works.
I am specifically talking about the way the new items come up on screen, it is delayed and I guess there is some animation added to it. 
Any ideas how this is done ?

Answer (score 2):

In the getView method of your Custom adapter, try adding the below animation to the convertView(list view item) and you should be able to do this..and its working for me

You need to set a TranslateAnimation to the view and that would do the trick for you.

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 200, 0 );
listView.clearAnimation();
translateAnim.setDuration(500);   
translateAnim.setFillBefore(true);   
listView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

Hope this helps :)