# Google+ profile like scrolling Effect

Tags: android, scroll, google-plus, scrollview

I'm working on Google plus android app and wondering how did they achieve **scrolling effect in profile view**, I searched through out web for 2 days and didn't find any tutorial on this, anybody do not know what i'm talking about can view the screenshots I've taken on my Nexus 7.

Now my curiosity is in knowing how to achieve this effect, anyone who have idea please guide me.[image: View the GIF]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to get a view to scroll along with your ListView?

Comment: can u add some sample code if you were able to acheive it

Answer (score 20):

**---OLD INFO----**

You can also achieve this effect by using the **Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager** a good example of scrolling tab header by [kmshack Github page](https://github.com/kmshack)

The Sample code is give in this [Here Git Hub link](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)

[image]

The explanation for the solution is begin described in the github page

**NEW UPADTE 25-4-2015**

A new Library works with app compact and tool bar [Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager-Header](https://github.com/kaedea/Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager-Header)

[image: Andriod-Seamless-ViewPager]

And there is another example also avilable **PlayNewsStandDemo**

Check this [PlayNewsStandDemo](https://github.com/naman14/PlayNewsStandDemo)

[image: PlayNewsStandDemo]

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 14):

The top is called a parallax effect, where the background image scrolls at half the speed of the actual scroll.

There is a good library you can use for that called Paralloid:

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid

The other part is the sticky tabs, which can be implemented using StickyListHeaders:

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve that using something we like to call **"Parallax Effect"**. I've made an easy to use library that can be used to get that effect.

If you want to use it on a RecyclerView you can use this library:
https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview

If you can use lists like ListView, ScrollView etc you can use this one:
https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-listview

I know this is a link only answer however such effect requires a lot of coding and therefor can't be posted as an answer.

Here are some screens of the effect you get:

[image][image]

Comment: how to get the right side style ? the action bar is transparent then fade to blue ?

Comment: Check my github. On the readme there's a snipet of how to do that. https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 6):

This is a good resource : http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/ --Explains the sticky footer, parallax and view hierarchy.

If your looking for the late animation on scroll, have a look here :

[google plus scrolling technique in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369901/google-plus-scrolling-technique-in-android)

Comment: you've provided me with first example link that's what i want, I want to achieve same effect in image and content in this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/72f2G.png could you please help ?

Comment: same as the `translation` of `image` and `content` relatively in G+ app

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` provided by google design library.
The following link provides a detailed explanation how to achieve what you want

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en